# How can I change the units of drawing from pixels to cm?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, drawing, dimensions, units

When drawing a rectangle or square, if drawn randomly it shows the units in a small box displayed in cm. If drawn by specifying the dimensions from the top ribbon, the unit is pixels instead of cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* input anything into measurement boxes...

10px - 10mm - 10cm - 10"

[image]

If you merely type a number, i.e. just 10... Photoshop automatically uses whatever the last unit used was.

So just add "cm" to the number in the box if you want it to be centimeters.